# What's the name value in response onChildAdded, Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Database Firebase in my project. I got a crazy confused with onChildAdded. I have code like this:

```
mEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
              @Override public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,
                @Nullable String stringS) {
   if (stringS != null
       && dataSnapshot.getKey()
      != null && !dataSnapshot.getKey().contains(stringS)) 
    {
     Log.e("=====", "onChildAdded: " + stringS +
           " getKey: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }....
```

- And I got logs here:

> =====: onChildAdded: -LMsqXJTn5DoMZTELzuz getKey:
>   -LMsqXJVyXWZKqDizrCt

- So what is the key of this "dataSnapshot" ???

[image: My firebase]

- In other cases I also got some opposite results, so it makes me really confused.

Added:

- Some other DataSnapshot , they both are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChildAdded` gets two arguments:

- The `DataSnapshot` that was just added
- The key of the **previous** child after which this new data snapshot was added

So in your sample, the new snapshot has key `-LMsqXJVyXWZKqDizrCt` and it was added after `-LMsqXJTn5DoMZTELzuz`.

Also see the [reference documentation for `onChildAdded`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener.html#onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot,%20java.lang.String)):

> `public abstract void onChildAdded (DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName)`
>
> This method is triggered when a new child is added to the location to which this listener was added.
>
> Parameters
>
> `snapshot` - An immutable snapshot of the data at the new child location
>
> **`previousChildName` - The key name of sibling location ordered before the new child. This will be null for the first child node of a location.**

Comment: So why in others DataSnapshot, I got they both were the same ?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. If you have a case like that, please show a repro of it.